# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error web config .net core web api

Tags: web-config

Detailed Error Information:

Module:
   IIS Web Core

Notification:
   BeginRequest

Handler:
   Not yet determined

Error Code:
   0x8007000d

Config Error:

Config File:

\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\web.config

can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure a .net core API to work in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612351/how-do-i-configure-a-net-core-api-to-work-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar challenge with an aspnet.core web application. I took these steps
1.  I installed the Windows Server Hosting (.exe) from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows
2.  I granted full permission to the application directory 
Hope this solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but different fix in case it helps someone. I *thought sure* that I had installed the .NET Core Runtime on the server. Turns out it wasn't actually there. Another sign that it's not installed is that in IIS Administrator, at the machine node, the Modules panel does not have the AspNetCoreModule registered (and indeed there was no aspnetcore.dll at \System32\inetsrv). Once I installed the .NET Core Runtime and restarted IIS, the application worked.

Another tip: installing the .NET Core SDK does not install the runtime components, including for IIS hosting. You must install specifically the Runtime to support apps on IIS.